Deleting source files when deleting GeoServer data store
I used the Importer plugin to add a GeoPackage to my GeoServer (2.25.1) in a new workspace.
Later I decided to remove the workspace. The uploaded file remains in $GEOSERVER_DATA/data/.
Is there a way to have GeoServer delete the file referenced by the created data store when deleting the workspace (or the data store manually first, if necessary) in the web interface?
